# Azure Logic Apps condition flow not working

Tags: azure

I am reading contents from service bus using `Logic Apps`, hence there are two cases:

1. If service bus contents contain text , then it
   means has to get contents from that Blob Storage link. e.g.
   https://blob-url-link
2. Else get contents from service bus directly.

My `If` condition always go to `else` or `false` condition, though service bus content got text of `<storage_url>`.

Is it because of octet data type or due to something else? Why `TRUE` condition is never satisfied?

Need your help in fixing Condition Logic, thanks in advance.

[Attached my Logic Apps flow that reads data from Service Bus and then it should write these contents into Azure Data Lake store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1vHj.png)

Comment: Post your `content` somewhere like to a webhook (you can use a temporary one at for instance [Hookbin](https://hookbin.com/)) to make sure it actually holds `<storage_url>`. I can imaging the `<`and `>` might be in there encoded...

Comment: In your exectution logs you have full access to the whole content - what comes in, what gies out. I thing the content of SB messages is Base64 encoded. But first check it in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As astaykov mentioned that servicebus message content is Base64 encode. We need to decode the base64 value to string and then compare it with supplied value.

In your case you need to change condition content to

```
base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])
```

[image]

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, it works. But my BLOB storage got contents of <storage_url>https://blob-url-link</storage_url>, hence i need to strip storage_url and get only the BLOB Link. I thought that Get Blob Content Using Path would that, but getting 400 - error message